# Lapply update string list in R

Tags: r, lapply

I have a question regarding updating a list

for example I have a string list,

```
a <-"aab"
b <-"aac"
c <-"aad"
...

newlist<-list(a,b,c...)
```

I would like to update add "c" for every element by using lapply. the expecting results would be:

```
> updated_list

[1]aabc
[2]aacc
[3]aadc
...
```

Comment: And what did you try so far? Where did you got stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `paste0` as the function argument to `lapply`:

```
updated_list <- lapply(newlist, function(x) paste0(x, "c"))
```

Comment: (+1) Or: `relist(paste0(newlist, "c"), newlist)`. I wonder if this is faster since we're skipping the `lapply` loop. But then, `relist` might include an internal loop as well...